# Can Rubymine support different versions of RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubymine

I have 2 unrelated Rubymine projects, one of which uses RSpec 2, the other uses RSpec3. The required version of rspec is defined in the Gemfile of each.

When I run the specs via Rubymine, it always uses the latest version of Rspec on my laptop and ignores the version defined in the Gemfile.

As I am unable to run the Rspec2 project with RSpec3, I have to manually uninstall RSpec3 when developing, then reinstall when developing the RSpec3 project.

Is there anyway I can force Rubymine to run a specific version of RSpec for a project?

Comment: Why do you think it ignores the version specified? You can check it also in Gemfile.lock (in addition, check if "Run in context of the bundle" option is turned on)